# Kafka Streams TopologyTestDriver is treating String key as an array of Bytes, throws ClassCastException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm attempting to set up a Kafka Streams unit test topology as described [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/test-kafka-streams-with-topologytestdriver/) in Confluent blog.

I should note that this works fine when running the topology for real.

I get the below error when writing to the topic.

```java
    @Test
    void processing() {
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        var myStream = new MyStream();
        myStream.startProcessing(builder);  // Serdes.String() for key and value
        var testDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(builder.build(), new Properties());
        var start = Instant.parse("2021-05-01T10:00:00Z");
        var inputTopic = testDriver.createInputTopic("my-events", new StringSerializer(), new StringSerializer(),
                start, Duration.ofMinutes(1));
        inputTopic.pipeInput("my-key", "my-value");  //boom
        
    }
```

MyStream.startProcessing is defined as:

```java
    public KStream<String, String> startProcessing(StreamsBuilder builder) {
        var stream = builder.<String, String>stream("my-events");
        stream.foreach( (k, v) -> System.out.println("k = " + k + " v =" + v));
    }
```

Using this for the Serdes

```java
...
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
...
```

Exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: ClassCastException invoking Processor. Do the Processor's input types match the deserialized types? Check the Serde setup and change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters. Make sure the Processor can accept the deserialized input of type key: [B, and value: [B.
Note that although incorrect Serdes are a common cause of error, the cast exception might have another cause (in user code, for example). For example, if a processor wires in a store, but casts the generics incorrectly, a class cast exception could be raised during processing, but the cause would not be wrong Serdes.

    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forwardInternal(ProcessorContextImpl.java:273)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:252)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.forward(ProcessorContextImpl.java:219)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.process(SourceNode.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.lambda$process$1(StreamTask.java:703)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:883)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.process(StreamTask.java:703)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver.completeAllProcessableWork(TopologyTestDriver.java:603)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver.pipeRecord(TopologyTestDriver.java:561)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TopologyTestDriver.pipeRecord(TopologyTestDriver.java:919)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TestInputTopic.pipeInput(TestInputTopic.java:115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.TestInputTopic.pipeInput(TestInputTopic.java:137)
    at io.myco.KStreamsTest.processing(KStreamsTest.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class [B cannot be cast to class java.lang.String ([B and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.KStreamPeek$KStreamPeekProcessor.process(KStreamPeek.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorAdapter.process(ProcessorAdapter.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.lambda$process$2(ProcessorNode.java:181)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:883)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorNode.process(ProcessorNode.java:181)
    ... 78 more
```

Comment: Where is `driver` or `MyStream` defined? Where are you setting any StreamsConfig settings? Can you please show the full stacktrace? Also, you'd use Serdes class, not StringSerializer

Comment: updated.  I don't see how I could use the Serdes class, the signature for `TopologyTestDriver.createInputTopic(...)` takes `Serializer<T>` and not Serdes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example from the book "**Mastering Kafka Streams and ksqlDB**" by **Mitch Seymour**, chapter 12, "**Testing, Monitoring and Deployment**",
adapted to your code:

**build.gradle dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
  testImplementation "org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams-test-utils:${kafkaVersion}"
  testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.15.0'
  testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.2'
}

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**Topology class:**

```
class MyTopology {

  public static Topology build() {
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    builder
        .stream("my-events", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()))
        .foreach( (k, v) -> System.out.println("k = " + k + " v =" + v))
        .to("my-outputs", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));

    return builder.build();
  }
}
```

**Topology test:**

```
class MyTopologyTest {
  private TopologyTestDriver testDriver;
  private TestInputTopic<String, String> inputTopic;
  private TestOutputTopic<String, String> outputTopic;

      @BeforeEach
      void setup() {
        Topology topology = MyTopology.build(); 

        Properties props = new Properties(); 
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "dummy:1234"); 

        testDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(topology, props); 
        var start = Instant.parse("2021-05-01T10:00:00Z");

        inputTopic =
            testDriver.createInputTopic( 
                "my-events",
                Serdes.String().serializer(),
                Serdes.String().serializer(),
                start, Duration.ofMinutes(1));

        outputTopic =
            testDriver.createOutputTopic( 
                "my-outputs",
                Serdes.String().deserializer(),
                Serdes.String().deserializer());
      }



      @Test
      void processing() {
    
        inputTopic.pipeInput("my-key", "my-value"); 
    
        assertThat(outputTopic.isEmpty()).isFalse(); 
    
        List<TestRecord<String, String>> outRecords =
          outputTopic.readRecordsToList(); 
        assertThat(outRecords).hasSize(1); 
    
        String key = outRecords.get(0).getKey(); 
        assertThat(key).isEqualTo("my-key");

        String value = outRecords.get(0).getValue(); 
        assertThat(value).isEqualTo("my-value");
      }


      @AfterEach
      void teardown() {
        testDriver.close(); 
      }
}
```

You can find the full code examples here: https://github.com/mitch-seymour/mastering-kafka-streams-and-ksqldb/tree/master/chapter-12/app

Comment: the `Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));` fixed it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change your serialization to [Serdes](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/TopologyTestDriver.html)

How to setup [TestToplogyDriver from Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/testing.html)

```
  //you can set up the corresponding serdes type of serialization, for e.g. if its not an event change it to string or long deserializer... whatever your setup is
  inputTest = testDriver.createInputTopic(someTestStream.INPUT, Serdes.StringSerde().serializer(), Serdes.StringSerde().serializer())

  outputTest = testDriver.createOutputTopic(someTestStream.OUTPUT, Serdes.StringSerde().deserializer(), Serdes.LongSerde().deserializer())

 ....
```

---

```
 // properties ref from KAFKA setup, looks like you updated it 
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9091");      
  props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomTimestampExtractor.class.getName());

  props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());

 props.setProperty(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());

 Topology topology = ...
 TopologyTestDriver driver = new TopologyTestDriver(topology, props);
```

[image: Kafka Apache Setup for Sedes Serialization]